# Finding the missing vertex $(x,y,z)$ of a rectangle whose other vertices are defined.

Tags: geometry, 3d

How do I find the missing fourth vertex $D$ of a rectangle, which has three vertices defined?

The Equation of the plane being $ax+by+cz+d=0$

Where,

$a = (By-Ay)(Cz-Az)-(Cy-Ay)(Bz-Az)$

$b = (Bz-Az)(Cx-Ax)-(Cz-Az)(Bx-Ax)$

$c = (Bx-Ax)(Cy-Ay)-(Cx-Ax)(By-Ay)$

$d = -(aAx+bAy+cAz)$

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: Just checking the following.  The triangle has three vertices.  One hypotenuse and two legs.  The missing vertex will create the two missing legs of the rectangle and share the hypotenuse.  So I want to use the distance formula for the triangle (x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2 + (z-z0)^2 = (hypotenuse length)^2.  Would I need any additional relationship to solve for x,y,z? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following picture that would help clarify my question.  To find W, add T and V and Subtract U.

**Equations**

1) **Main Equation**

$w = t + v - u$

2) ***3D Point Equations***

$(x,y,z)\mathbf{_{w}} = (x,y,z)\mathbf{_{t}} + (x,y,z)\mathbf{_{v}} - (x,y,z)\mathbf{_{u} }$

3) **Individual 3D Coordinate Equations**

$x\mathbf{_{w}} = x\mathbf{_{t}} + x\mathbf{_{v}} - x\mathbf{_{u} }$

$y\mathbf{_{w}} = y\mathbf{_{t}} + y\mathbf{_{v}} - y\mathbf{_{u} }$

$z\mathbf{_{w}} = z\mathbf{_{t}} + z\mathbf{_{v}} - z\mathbf{_{u} }$

[image: Finding Missing 4th Vertex of Parallelogram]

Finding Missing 4th Vertex of a Parallelogram

Image Courtesy of:
http://www.goldensoftware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=8174

Extending this to a 3D would mean just performing the same operation on the Z-Axis.

Comment: Actually, pursuant to the diagram, to find W, add T and V and subtract U!

Comment: @Senex, thanks for the correction! I corrected the mistake.  My original formula of W = T + U - V has been corrected to W = T + V - U.